# Connection to a JDBC MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a JDBC MySQL database using Java, but I am getting the following error when I try to run my program:-

> No suitable driver found for
>   a9442ca6-992c-411b-8bda-a42f00a0ab2e.mysql.sequelizer.com

I downloaded the following Jar file and added it to my project:

```
    mysql-connector-java5.1.34-bin.jar
```

I'm not sure if I need to add some kind of 'import' statement in my declaration maybes? Any help would be much appreciated.

My code is as follows:-

```
package dvddblibrary;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DBConnect {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {



            try
            {
                String host = "xxx";
                String uName = "xxx";
                String uPass = "xxx";

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName,   uPass);

            }
            catch (SQLException err)
            {
                System.out.println(err.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please, could you at least help us by posting your current code.

Comment: Did you run the program in command line or in an IDE like Eclipse? If you're running it in command line, you've to include the jar in command for both compilation and execution part

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the driver first, which is a side effect of loading the class. Try

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

MySQL even say you need to do

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

for some "broken Java implementations" but I never found that necessary. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html.

Comment: If using Java SE 7, this is not needed anymore.

Comment: At least when this is done and it produces a `ClassNotFoundException` we know that the true reason is that the jar is not on the classpath.

Comment: But that's not the problem... For me, looks more like OP did a wrong copy/paste of code and has the wrong class name in `Class.forName`.

Comment: But if you have a copy/paste error in `Class.forName` you get a `ClassNotFounException` whereas if you don't have it on the classpath or use Java 6 or before and omit the `Class.forName()` you will get the "no suitable driver" error message. Let's maybe wait for the OP to clarify or paste complete code. My answer was too early.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry where do I put this line of code - Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

Comment: Somewhere before you do `DriverManager.getConnection()`.

Comment: Im actually developing in NetBeans. Not sur eif this info helps. Anyway I entered the line of code just before 'DriveManager.getConnection() and got this design time error - "unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"

Comment: This is not the error I mentioned since it happens at compile time, not at runtime.  If you don't know what it means I recommend to learn the basics before you move on to JDBC. Get a decent textbook or try googling for "Java exception handling".

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
package dvddblibrary;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String host = "xxx";
            String uName = "xxx";
            String uPass = "xxx";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        } catch (SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will get a compilation error because the try/catch block is not covering the "ClassNotFoundException" exception.

Answer (score 0):

Download the file from [ http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ ]. Extract it and you will find a .jar file inside the lib folder. Copy this file into the lib/ folder of your project.

It may cause that problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code;

1) You have to add this on the top of your try block;

```
        // Add this
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

2) And **your connection string is not valid**, try a valid connection string in your host;

```
        String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/XXX";
```

The complete code is as below, (I have no mysql database by the way, just run this to get connection error, not "" error)

```
package dvddblibrary;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // Add this
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //String host = "xxx";  // this is not valid, update with a valid connection string
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/XXX";
            String uName = "xxx";
            String uPass = "xxx";

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

        } catch (SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

And the output is as below, instead of getting your "**No suitable driver found**" error, I get a connection error (because I don't have a mysql database on localhost :) );

```
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

If you just update the code, as far as your mysql database is up and your host is valid, **this code will work fine**.